# Assessing supervisors?

Tags: supervision

Since professors are assessed by students, I think many problems PhD students confront could be solved, if they could assess their supervisors. At the end, it is the PhD student who is paying with his time and very low scholarship (in contrast to a industry job) for a good-quality supervision. And - believe it or not - many famous professors aren't good supervisors. Some of them don't have the time to supervise their student due to many projects and postdocs. So often a post doc is assigned to the supervision of a PHD student. Is assessment of one's supervisors a way how to put the things right again?

Comment: I would be surprised if any university does not have policies in place to address issues between supervisors and candidates. A simple assessment would not solve anything, if you have problems that a conversation with your supervisor cannot solve, find how to escalate things further.

Comment: That's a very philosophical question that I think is really not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Also, I think nobody here will challenge you on your claim that not all famous researchers are good supervisors.

Comment: If you supervisor gives you a bad assessment, then you don't finish your PhD. If you give your supervisor a bad assessment, then... (presumably nothing happens).

Comment: I've been told a variety of bad things about Professor X, only to find my personal experience with Professor X has been just fine and sometimes they've even been great and very helpful. It's much the same problem as having a job outside of academia - some supervisors were terrible to me, and yet sometimes other people got along with them just fine. It's very hard to tell the difference between a bad fit and a genuinely terrible person, and to-date there seems to be no method that solves this problem, and usually they create other issues. RateMyProfessor exists, so you can see the pro/cons.

Comment: @BrianDHall Thanks for your comment. I guess that is a good reason why the things are how they are. Good to hear that things turned out fine for you.

Comment: @Derb I do wish there were a better solution, because I've certainly had problems with people before and sometimes it was potentially predictable based on others experience, but other times it came completely out of the blue. Sometimes a cantankerous person is helpful in select situations, and sometimes a nice person is incredibly unhelpful. And I've even found people I would have rated highly one month were incredibly unhelpful the next month and I wanted to boot them into the stratosphere - to find the next month they were actually helpful again. Individuals are hard to predict!

Comment: "it is the PhD student who is paying with his time and very low scholarship". Nobody forced anyone to do a PhD. If you do not like the pay, the long hours or the hardships of the PhD you are welcome to find a work in the real world. Although, despite the myth that "the grass is greener or the other side", work in industry is no walk in the park either. But on both cases, if the PhD student or the industry employee fails on his "job", it is he that suffers the consequences and not the senior party (professor or employer). So, expecting things to be different is not realistic.

Comment: The "PhD student" is costing the institution very real money, and a lot of it. In advisor's and other's salaries, in providing office space, in providing infrastructure (labs, library, ...) for research. They gamble to get it back (in prestige, papers, research results that can be monetized, directly or indirectly). But free it isn't.

Comment: @MaartenBuis It's basically a variant of Schopenhauer's Law: If your supervisor gives you a bad assessment, then you don't finish your PhD. If you give your supervisor a bad assessment, then you don't finish your PhD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such assessment would be of very little value (or use, really). The selection of potential advisors is limited; each of them has an advisor-advisee relationship lasting a couple of years, for a very limited number of advisees; if somebody qualifies (or not) as an advisor depends on a raft of issues, of which "student satisfaction" occupies last position (is tenured, got the grant financing the student, heads the research group in the topic, has built up the lab and other infrastructure to house students, and a few others come way, way before).